# SpriteKit, get rect of transparent value

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit, skspritenode

`SKSpriteNode` is new to me. For the image below, I am wondering what are some ways I can get the rect of the non-transparent part using sprite kit.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by detect?

Comment: like get the rect of the blue parts

Comment: You want the minimum `CGRect` that contains all the points with non-zero alpha?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [calculateAccumulatedFrame](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/calculateAccumulatedFrame).